# PHP como deixar select setado

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-select

Tenho um select que pega os dados do banco para fazer uma inserção:

```html
 <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="marca">Marca</label>
            <?php 
            $link = open_database();
            $query = "SELECT marca_id, marca_nome FROM marca";
            $queryidmarca = mysqli_query($link, $query); ?>
            <select class='form-control' id='marca' name="veiculo['marca_id']">
                <option value="">-Selecione-</option>
                <?PHP while ($tipo = mysqli_fetch_array($queryidmarca)){ ?>
                <option value="<?PHP echo $tipo['marca_id'] ?>"><?PHP echo $tipo['marca_nome'] ?></option>
    <?PHP } ?>
         </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Queria saber como faço para deixar selecionado a informação que foi salvo neste select em outro select que esta em outro form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes.

Você terá `2 querys` para isso:

1. Para buscar o valor que você salvou;
2. Para gerar `input` do tipo `select` com as devidas `option`.

Aqui você busca o registo que foi salvo anteriormente e armazena em uma variável (tem que ser 1 valor só, então você precisa ter o `WHERE` para buscar o registro salvo anteriormente):

```
$query1 = "SELECT marca_id, marca_nome FROM marca WHERE registro = 20";
...(faz o fetch, etc)...
$opcaoSalva = $array['marca_id'];
```

Com essa variável `$opcaoSalva` você sabe a opção que do registro que você busco correto !? Então agora você vai gerar seu campo `input` do tipo `select`, e enquanto gerar as `option` você irá verificar se ela é o mesmo `marca_id` da sua variável `$opcaoSalva`.

```
$query2 = "SELECT marca_id, marca_nome FROM marca";
...
while ($tipo = mysqli_fetch_array($queryidmarca)){ ?>

   <option value="<?php echo $tipo['marca_id'] ?>" <?php echo ($tipo['marca_id'] == $opcaoSalva) ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?php echo $tipo['marca_nome'] ?></option>
```

Então no while, vc vai gerar todas opções, mas enquanto você gera, irá verificar se `$tipo['marca_id']` é o mesmo do `$opcaoSalva`, e caso for, ele imprime `selected` dentro da tag `<option>` (que é padrão do `html` isso).

```
<?php echo ($tipo['marca_id'] == $opcaoSalva) ? 'selected' : '' ?>
```

Comment: Obrigado, Resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o atributo `selected`, e fazer uma condição ternária para imprimir o `selected`.

Por exemplo:

```
<select name="veiculo">
  <option <?php echo ($condicao === true) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Opção</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Esse código deu erro de sytaxe na linha do option

Comment: Tente novamente, eu tinha cometido um erro. :)

Comment: Agora sim.
Mais essa variável $condição, de onde ela vem ?
Porque apareceu como variável indefinida.

Comment: Eu usei ela como um exemplo. Aquilo é como se fosse um `if` curto. Chama-se operador ternário. Você pode prosseguir da forma como precisar. :)

Comment: Desculpe se estou sendo muito leigo, mais eu entendi o if ternário, só não sei como fazer uma condição que traga o item selecionado